# Ходатайствовать - этимология слова

Tags: этимология

Ходатайствовать - это просить, хлопотать за кого-то, быть чьим-то протеже. Слово, как я понимаю, русское. Но интересно, а как оно образовалось?
Моя версия - от слова "ходить", то есть, обивать пороги, прося за кого-то, обходить множество инстанций.
Я права?

Comment: По этому вопросу полезно будет посмотреть [этот ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/464048/183462) в другой теме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вы правы. По крайней мере, корень, а так же схожие слова в других языках, наталкивают именно на эту версию как наиболее вероятную.

Answer (score 2):

ну ходатайствовать - от "ходатай". Неужели не знаете этого слова?
Тот, кто ходит (к начальству, барину или по кабинетам) с каким-то прошением, поручением.

А суффикс (вернее всего - два сросшихся) "-атай": глашатай, завсегдатай, соглядатай.

Comment: Слово "ходатай" я, естественно, знаю. Как бы не в диком лесу росла))) Но его этимология меня интересует точно так же

Comment: Так я же вам её и написал?!

Answer (score 0):

С одной стороны оно так, а если рассмотреть "тай" то выйдет совсем интересно. Как Вам так: ходить за вора, любопытный сюжет.

Comment: Тай - это тайна: тай, тайна, потаённый. А вор - тать. Хотя так же не далеко от тай, ибо вор действует тайно, исподтишка.

Answer (score -1):

Выложу свою версию.

1. Полностью согласен что ХОДАТАЙСТВО (ХОДАТАЙ) происходит от однокоренных слов ХОД, ХОДИТЬ, ХОДУН.
2. А вот слово ТАЙ – это завершение вершины, ВЕЛИКИЙ. Это старорусское слово, к русскому отношения не имеет. Слово ТАЙ от народов живших на этих территориях и давших названия географическим и природным явлениям.
   киТАЙ (Кий-Тай стена великая),
   алТАЙ (золотой великий),
   ТАЙфун (великий ветер),
   ТАЙга (великий лес),
   ТАЙмыр (огромный холодный).
   Получается ХОДАТАЙ - человек который ходит, отбивает ноги, просит и является по сути великим завершающим, уважаемым, т.к. от его "ног" и его почитаемости в обществе зависит услышат его просьбу или нет, от этого зависит судьба обвиняемого.

Comment: "Народно-этимологические" версии никому не интересны на этом ресурсе и обычно удаляются.