# Ходатай, соглядатай — этимология

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Что это за странный способ формирования отглагольных существительных **ходатай, соглядатай и прелагатай** — путем добавления "ай" к основе глагола?

Answer (score 1):

Вот как тут угадать, что хочет освежить в памяти автор вопроса - этимологию слов или способ словообразования?

Ни в том, ни в другом случае «путём добавления "ай" к основе глагола» не происходит НИЧЕГО.

Слова:

- вожатай
- глашатай
- завсегдатай
- оратай
- прелагатай
- ходатай
- соглядатай

оканчиваются *непродуктивным суффиксом* ***-атай***, отнюдь не всегда лепящемуся к глаголу (завсегдатай - из наречия "всегда" сформировался, по Фасмеру).

ЭТИМОЛОГИЯ

**[ходатай](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9)**

> Происходит от церк.-слав., ст.-слав. ходатаи (πρέσβυς, μεσίτης; Клоц.,
>   Супр.), далее от сущ. ход, из праслав. *xodъ, от кот. в числе прочего
>   произошли: ст.-слав. ходъ (др.-греч. βάδισμα, δρόμος), русск. ход,
>   укр. хід (род. п. ходу), болг. ход, сербохорв. хо̑д (род. п. хо̏да),
>   словенск. hòd (род. п. hódа) и словенск. hȏd (род. п. hоdа), чешск.
>   chod, словацк. chod, польск. chód (род. п. chodu), chód. Связано с индоевр. корнем *sed- > «ходить, сидеть»; х-
>   произошло из s- после приставок реr-, pri-, u-; ср. знач. др.-инд.
>   āsad- «ступить, пойти, достигать», utsad- «отходить, выходить,
>   исчезать», авест. āhad- «подходить». Родственно греч. ὁδός «путь»,
>   греч. ὁδίτης «странник», греч. ὁδεύω «странствую».

**[Прелагатай](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/300839/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9)** - обнаружилось только лексическое значение:  посланец • разведчик • соглядатай;

а если поднатужиться, то в "Зведений словник застарілих та маловживаних слів" и [шпигун, наклепник, перевертень.](https://staroukr.academic.ru/3507/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9)

---

---

О птицах - кстати:

**[завсегдатай](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9)**

> Конфиксное производное от наречия всегда, далее от праслав. , от кот.
>   в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. вьсегда, русск.
>   всегда, укр. всíгда, всíгди, белор. всегды, сербохорв. сва̏гда,
>   словенск. vsègdar, vsîgdar, польск. wszegdy. Из предшествующего
>   *vьxogda. Вместе с тем ряд форм указывает на *vьxoda: болг. възда, сербохорв. вазда, словенск. vazdar, чешск. vezda, vezdy, veždy,
>   польск. wżdy, weżdy, в.-луж. vždy. Второй ряд форм соответствует лит.
>   visadà «всегда», латышск. visad. Окончание -y, возм., соответствует
>   лит. visadõs. Первый ряд форм содержит -гда, подобно когда́, тогда́,
>   иногда́. По мнению И. Шмидта, Мейе, эти формы восходят к *kogo goda,
>   *togo goda и т. д., в данном случае — *вьхого года. Однако вероятнее сближать -гда во всех этих формах с лит. kadà, др.-инд. kadā́, авест.
>   kadā «когда», на другие образования оно было распространено по
>   аналогии. Русск. всегда́ ср. с сербохорв. сва шта (= vьse čьto) «все».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось разъяснить **[конфикс](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/612/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81)**:

> (от лат. confixum — совместно взятое). Приставка и суффикс,
>   одновременным присоединением образующие слово. *Подстаканник,
>   расшуметься.*

Примечательно, что Шанский не усматривает никакого конфикса, начинает плясать сразу от "завсегда":

> Искон. Суф. производное (ср. *[глашатай, вожатый,](https://etymological.academic.ru/1290/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9)* см.) от
>   *завсегда,* преф. образования от *всегда*.

См. также [вожатай](https://etymological.academic.ru/567/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9) - и далее по Шанскому.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. Жаль, что я пропустил его в своё время.

Автор вопроса прав в том, что всё это отглагольные образования, только на -**атай**. Много интересной и системообразующей информации по этому словообразованию [приводит](http://wordhist.narod.ru/zavsegdataj.html) В.В. Виноградов в своей "Истории слов". Процитирую пару первых абзацев по ссылке, но посоветую прочитать всю статью целиком:

> А. И. Соболевский указывал на то, что это— потомство древних
> существительных на -ай. «Срв. ц.-сл. возатай возница (употребляемое
> Гнедичем), глашатай, съгл#датай, ходатай, ратай и т. п., др.-русск.
> слугатай (письмо Ио. Грозного к Курбскому).
>
> Современный русский язык сохранил несколько таких существительных с
> древним окончанием и склонением: ратай, оратай, завсегдатай,
> содержатай, не принадлежащих совсем или по преимуществу литературному
> языку» (РФВ, 1905, № 1—2, т. 53, с. 10).
>
> Но в этом общем морфологическом анализе русских именных образований на
> -атай недостаточно дифференцированы разные исторические пласты лексики и разные модели словообразования. Ходатай, соглядатай, глашатай (ср.
> древнерусск. водатай) и т. п. — старославянизмы. По их типу были
> сформированы в русском литературном языке XVI — XVII вв. несколько
> семантически близких слов: позыватай (ср. глашатай), вожатай,
> провожатай, праздношатай (ср. водатай, ходатай) и нек. др.; ср.
> содержатай. Несколько обособленно стоят севернорусские слова — ратай,
> оратай. И из всех этих отглагольных образований резко выделяется своей
> наречно-местоименной основой слово завсегдатай.

Answer (score 0):

Оконечное «ай» характерно для глаголов волеизъявления: не мешай, играй, надевай, не гавкай…

Имена существительные с подобным признаком встречаются много реже: каравай, урожай, край, случай, лишай, лай, вертухай…
Очевидно, что отглагольные образования являются только частью из них.

В составе отглагольных можно выделить (совсем уж) незначительную часть имен нарицательных: 
краснобай, глашатай, оратай, шалтай (диал.)...

Но если сюда же отнести имена нарицательные с оконечным «яй» (смягченное «ай»): жердяй, негодяй, скупердяй, разгильдяй, лентяй, слюнтяй…, то «одиночество» слов «соглядатай» и «ходатай» уже не будет выглядеть таким уж безысходным, а способ их образования - странным.